# RN axios too long to respond after switching the airplane mode on/off

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I would like to ask for suggestion or recommendation for this scenario.

When the mobile lost it's internet connection and after a while, then internet connection is resumed.
After that, all pending requests to the api are too long to respond.

My replication for this is turning the airplane mode on/off.
I need to force closed the app more than 2x to work it normally.

Even the set timeout on axios is not working.

Any suggestion for this one?

For my axios set up

```
export const axios = api.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    source: API_SOURCE,
    apiVersion: API_VERSION,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  cancelToken: source.token,
})
```

For my api request

```
 async testApiCall(params: { status: boolean; set?: boolean }, state) {
      try {
        const { status, set = true } = params

        console.log('before call')

        const result = (await setStatus({
          online: status
        })) as any

        console.log('after call', result)

        return result
      } catch (error) {
        return error
      }
    }
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo . create a listener in app.js everytime its get disconnected navigate to error screen "internet offline"

Comment: Hi @ucup, yes I have this one, checking before the request.
The issue upon the reconnection, the internet is connected but the api response from axios is to long.

Comment: you can cancel axios request (https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation) and you may need to re fetch api when go back to previous screen

Comment: Hi I do this, it will implement globally right?
then i need to renew re create the instance of axios?

Comment: Any update on this one I am facing same issue